# iOS simulator ghost image edge left over on the screen after animation

Tags: ios, image, screen, simulator

I added spring option to an UIImage. It worked fine on my phone, very nice. Bouncy and smooth.
But when I run it on the iOS simulators, it always leaves some edges on the screen.
It becomes a problem when I need to upload screenshots to App Store.

[image]

This is my code:

```
let theTile = numberTile
let bounds = theTile.bounds

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
theTile.bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width * 1.2, height: bounds.size.height * 1.2)
}, completion: nil)
```

This is the shrink back code

```
let theTile = numberTile
let bounds = theTile.bounds

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
theTile.bounds = CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: self.size)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You are screwing up the bounds of the view over and over. Where are you calling this.  Did select?

Comment: I call this when this UIImageView (numberTile) is tapped. What is the problem by using bounds? I can try frame or size to see if it makes difference. Thanks

Comment: Add auto reverse as an option. Or in the completion shrink the bounds back to the original size

Comment: I do here it shrink back when press it again. the screenshot is actually the one after shrink back. My logic is press it, increase the size, press it again, change back to the original size. shrink back code added in the original post

Comment: Where is shrink back

Comment: just added. one the phone, everything is fine.

Comment: Are you adding a sub layer or view anywhere?  In layout sub views?

Comment: Just ViewController and some UIImageViews which created by code.

Comment: but do you add any views in layoutSubviews or in cell for row

Comment: No other views.

Comment: Is this a collection view. Can I see your cell for row or cell configure

Answer (score 0):

Try this although this might not be your only issue.  If that is a collection view I would need to see your cell for row function as you may be loading a cell with the bounds messed up to start with.  Here is a suggestion though.  Animate the transform instead.

```
//to animate larger
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        theTile.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }, completion: nil)

//animate smaller
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        theTile.transform = .identity
    }, completion: nil)
```

If this is a collection view in cell for row you may need to check for selected index but def if not selected you need to set the transform to identity.

**EDIT:**
You say this does not fix the issue.  What environment are you running?  Type of Mac.  I personally believe it is a code issue somewhere else as I have written tons of animation code and never seen this bug.  Here is a minimum example that does **not** create "ghost layers" on my device or simulator.  If you can make a minimal example that does it would help a lot... Until then I think it is something in your code possibly your collection view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var box : UIView = {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        v.center = self.view.center
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        self.view.addSubview(box)
        box.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        fireEvent()
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    func fireEvent(){
        if box.transform == .identity{
            //to animate larger
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                self.box.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
            }, completion: nil)
        }else{
            //animate smaller
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                self.box.transform = .identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it. still the same issue. I think this is the problem of the simulator. Might be video card related?

Comment: Bump the dampening up to a higher number. It’s possible you are still animating when you snap the image.

Comment: That's didn't help. Thanks